# Count number of items with active state

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a function to toggle an active state on clicked list items:

Vue

```
toggleActive: function(s){
  s.active = !s.active;
},
```

Pug

```
li(v-for='property in properties', v-on:click='toggleActive(property)'
```

How can I check for the number of items that have an active state later on? Ideally I want to set a variable as the number of active state items.

I initially thought of something like this:

```
var count = this.properties.active.length;
```

But can't get it working.

Comment: This is not much code. But going off what I see is you would need this.properties.active to be an array. If it wasn't then you would just need to do this.properties.active

Comment: It is enough code for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the ES6 Filter on an array/object:

`this.properties.filter(value => value.active === true).length;`

You could shorten it down to:

`this.properties.filter(v => v.active).length`